# Symfony Iterating over ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my app I have 2 entities; User & Booking.

Booking entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="booking")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BookingRepository")
 */
class Booking
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $isActive;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="bookings")
 */
private $user;
```

User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="This email address is already in use")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Booking", mappedBy="user")
 * @Expose
 */
private $bookings;

/**
 * User constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I tried to add a function to my user entity that returns the active booking, I tried this:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getActiveBooking()
{
    foreach( $this->bookings as $booking ) {
        if( $booking->getIsActive() ) {
            return $booking;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error: Error: Call to a member function getRoom() on null

When I call it using `$user->getActiveBooking()->getRoom()->getId()`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user you are working with has an active booking.

`getActiveBooking()` is returning null because it seems user does not have an active booking.

That's why you are getting an error that you cannot call `getRoom()` on `null` because the previous function has returned `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the database, and is_active field is set to 1

Comment: And the user_id is the same id as the user you are using? Have you tried `dump` ing the user and checking the associations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a joinColumn like this:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="bookings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $user;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the $user relationship is already present in the booking entity

Comment: Well. Have you tried to see if your if is true? 
foreach( $this->bookings as $booking ) {
        if( $booking->getIsActive() ) {
            die("its true once at least");
        }
    }